# getting started with Tensor Flow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to learn tensor flow. In the given example how can we define rank and shape?? I mean how to find the rank and shape??

```
    3 # a rank 0 tensor; this is a scalar with shape []
    [1. ,2., 3.] # a rank 1 tensor; this is a vector with shape [3]
    [[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.]] # a rank 2 tensor; a matrix with shape [2, 3]
    [[[1., 2., 3.]], [[7., 8., 9.]]] # a rank 3 tensor with shape [2, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rank is the number of dimensions in the tensor. Refer to:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor

> The total number of indices required to identify each component uniquely is equal to the dimension of the array, and is called the order, degree or rank of the tensor.

Shape describes the number of elements in each dimension of the tensor.

In the given example,

```
[1. ,2., 3.]
```

is a set of numbers with only one dimension. This is called a vector and generally used to represent a line.

```
[[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.]]
```

is a set of numbers with two dimensions. This is called a matrix and generally represents a set of lines geometrically. (Each line described by elements in each of the inner brackets)

This can be generalized to more than two dimensions.
More generally, all these sets of numbers are known as Tensors. TensorFlow uses these sets of numbers as a data structure.

Comment: as you said that Rank is the number of dimensions in the tensor like by seeing the braces we can find out the rank. Is there any such thing to find out the shape of tensor? I dont understand in the third example how the shape is [ 2, 1, 3]  when compared to second example??

Comment: Consider [ [[1,11,12,13], [2,22,23,24]], [[3,33,34,35], [4,44,45,46]], [[5,55,56,57], [6,66,67,68]] ]. In this, there are 4 elements in the innermost box, 2 such "4 element boxes" packed into another box, and 3 of those in the outermost box. 
So, the shape of tensor is: [3, 2, 4] and the rank of tensor is 3

Similarly, in your example, there are 3 numbers in innermost box, 1 "3 element box" packed into another box (given by "[[" and "]]"), and 2 such boxes in the outermost box. Thus, Shape is [2,1,3]

Comment: You MUST study Linear Algebra and Calculus before you start using TensorFlow. Those topics will cover all your doubts and make you understand your TensorFlow code better. Consider learning Python as well, if you haven't already.